# TextPosition Bounding Box PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am trying, from a TextPosition, to draw the corresponding glyph bounding box as shown in the PDF 32000 documentation.
[image]

Here is my function that does the computation from **glyph space** to **user space**

```
@Override 
protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
    PDFont font = pos.getFont();
    
    BoundingBox bbox = font.getBoundingBox();
    
    Rectangle2D.Float rect = new Rectangle2D.Float(bbox.getLowerLeftX(), bbox.getUpperRightY(), 
            bbox.getWidth(), bbox.getHeight());
    
    AffineTransform at = pos.getTextMatrix().createAffineTransform();
    
    if (font instanceof PDType3Font) {
        at.concatenate(font.getFontMatrix().createAffineTransform());
    } else {
        at.scale(1 / 1000f, 1 / 1000f);
    }
    Shape shape = at.createTransformedShape(rect);
    rectangles.add(fillBBox(text));
    
            
    super.processTextPosition(text);
}
```

And Here is the function that draws the extracted rectangles:

```
private void drawBoundingBoxes() throws IOException {
    
    String fileNameOut = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf(".")) + "_OUT.pdf";
    log.info("Drawing Bounding Boxes for TextPositions");
    
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, 
            document.getPage(document.getNumberOfPages()-1),
            PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false , true );
    contentStream.setLineWidth(1f);
    contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.RED);
    
    try{
        for (Shape p : rectangles) {
            p = all.get(0);
        double[] coords = new double[6];
        GeneralPath g = new GeneralPath(p.getBounds2D());
        for (PathIterator pi = g.getPathIterator(null);
             !pi.isDone();
             pi.next()) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(coords));
            switch (pi.currentSegment(coords)) {
            case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                System.out.println("move to");
                contentStream.moveTo ((float)coords[0], (float) coords[1]);
                break;
                
            case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                System.out.println("line to");
                contentStream.lineTo ((float)coords[0], (float) coords[1]);
                break;
                
            case PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO:
                System.out.println("cubc to");
                contentStream.curveTo((float)coords[0], (float) coords[1],
                        (float)coords[2], (float) coords[3], 
                        (float)coords[4],(float) coords[5]);
                break;
                
            case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
                System.out.println("close");
                contentStream.closeAndStroke();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("no shatt");
                break;
            }
            
        }
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        contentStream.close();
        document.save(new File(fileNameOut));
    }
}
```

Then when I try to draw on the pdf I get the following result for the first letter (the capital V)
[image]

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the DrawPrintTextLocations example, look at the cyan part, that one has the real bounding boxes (most of the time)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am having some troubles with the bounding box in some cases there is a displacement. I printed the bounding boxes extracted for two files If you can have look:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aQ6TyGVAybmlNvapCodY0Rp7IRpYm5_7

I could't tell why it is happening in some places and not the others.
Thanks in adavance

Comment: That doesn't help much, this seems to be a PDF of a screenshot. It is unclear if this came from one PDF page or from several: In the "Lavande" PDF, there is a displacement on the right part but not on the left. I would have to get the original PDF. If this was from several pages, then I suspect it is related to the cropbox. If it is from one PDF page, then I'd suspect that this is an image of text with hidden text at the wrong position.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I added the original files in the same folder.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I also set the SuppressDuplicateOverlappingText to false and I got the same results for the for both files. So apparently no hidden text!

Comment: The DrawPrintTextLocations example places the cyan boxes at the correct position. so something went wrong while adapting the example (did you?). `fillBBox` is missing, and `drawBoundingBoxes` is never called in your code above.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr you were completely right! I was applying translation the textMatrix by mistake which causes this effect!

Comment: Glad to hear that. The best would be that you answer your question yourself, i.e. tell what steps helped solving the problem, so that maybe other people will also be helped.

Comment: Yeah I will do a complete post answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Mr. D,

I tested your code and the only change I needed to make it work was to invert the Y axis. The reason this is needed is because the origin in the **PDF User Space** is located at the bottom-left corner, unlike the origin of the **Java 2D User Space** which is located on the top-left corner<sup>[1]</sup>.

> **8.3.2.3 User Space**
>
> The user space coordinate system shall be initialized to a default state for each page of a document. The **CropBox** entry in the page dictionary shall specify the rectangle of user space corresponding to the visible area of the intended output medium (display window or printed page). The positive x axis extends horizontally to the right and the positive y axis vertically upward, as in standard mathematical practice (subject to alteration by the **Rotate** entry in the page dictionary). The length of a unit along both the x and y axes is set by the **UserUnit** entry (PDF 1.6) in the page dictionary (see Table 30). If that entry is not present or supported, the default value of 1⁄72 inch is used. This coordinate system is called default user space.<sup>[2]</sup>

#### Source Code

```
@Override 
protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
    try {
        PDFont font = pos.getFont();

        BoundingBox bbox = font.getBoundingBox();

        Rectangle2D.Float rect = new Rectangle2D.Float(bbox.getLowerLeftX(), bbox.getUpperRightY(),
                    bbox.getWidth(), bbox.getHeight());

        AffineTransform at = pos.getTextMatrix().createAffineTransform();

        if (font instanceof PDType3Font) {
            at.concatenate(font.getFontMatrix().createAffineTransform());
        } else {
            at.scale(1 / 1000f, 1 / 1000f);
        }

        Shape shape = at.createTransformedShape(rect);

        // Invert Y axis
        Rectangle2D bounds = shape.getBounds2D();
        bounds.setRect(bounds.getX(), bounds.getY() - bounds.getHeight(), bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());

        rectangles.add(bounds);

        super.processTextPosition(text);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

#### References

1. [Java 2D API Concepts: Coordinates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/coordinate.html)
2. Document management - Portable document format - Part 1: PDF 1.7, [PDF 32000-1:2008](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), Section 8.3: Coordinate Systems, page 115

Comment: Answer is good but that is not the only problem he had. His bounding box is for all glyphs, not for the individual glyph. Thus too big.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the coordinate system. But as @Tilman said the problem was also about getting the bounding box for each character. I found the right way to do it in DrawPrintTextLocations.java

Comment: That is a really neat example, thanks for sharing. See example here:  [DrawPrintTextLocations.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/DrawPrintTextLocations.java)